# How do I make the bot respond when someone mentions it? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Here is the code I've tried:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mention in message.content.split():
        await client.say("You can type `!vx help` for more info.")
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Could you elaborate how it doesn't work for you? Do you get an error? Did you follow any tutorial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using command decorators, you can do:

```py
from discord.ext import commands # necessary for this task

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"))
```

Or using an `on_message()` event, this is one of many ways you can check the mention:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("You can type `!vx help` for more info")
```

Also, I noticed your method of sending a message to the channel wasn't quite right.

In d.py rewrite (v1.x), you have an `abc.Messageable` object, which is something like a server's text channel, or a DM or a group chat, as the name implies.

And this object has a method called `send()` which allows you to send content. Some common instances where you'll be finding this would be; `ctx.send()` when you're using command decorators - they have `Context` as the first parameter - and `message.channel.send()` when you're using the `on_message()` event like you are. It will also appear in some other places, but these will be the most common.

You've got the right idea about it being a coroutine, and therefore needing to `await` it. In the documentation it'll state whether something is a coroutine or not.

---

**References:**

- [`commands.when_mentioned_or()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or)
- [`ClientUser.mentioned_in()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.mentioned_in)
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) - See what you can `send()` messages to.
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) - This inherits from `abc.Messageable`.
- [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Answer (score 2):

```
 @client.event async def on_message(message):
     if client.user.mention in message.content.split():
         await client.say("You can type `!vx help` for more info.")
```

Instead of content.split() use content:
And instead of client.say use message.channel.send()
so we will get

```
 @client.event
 async def on_message(message):
     if client.user.mention in message.content:
         await message.channel.send("You can type `!vx help` for more info.")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.event#ping reply
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot == False and bot.user.mentioned_in(message) and len(message.content) == len(bot.user.mention)+1:
    await message.channel.send(f'Hello! I am the {bot.user.mention}!\nMy Prefix is $')
  else:
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The method is quite simple, in the bot.event the bot will read every message, check for the following

1. That the ping is not from a different bot, it's from a user only
2. That the bot has been mentioned in the message
3. That only the bot has been mentioned, it avoids the accidental mention/ping in a convo. that +1 in length is for the newline character.

`bot.process_commands(message)` is there so that if it's not a ping then the bot can process the message/command further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution using a class. I was having issues with the exact situation and eventually managed to solve it, but couldn't find any examples like this. The key is the `if self.user in message.mentions:` line.

`message.mentions` refers to a list of users so you can check for yourself or anyone else.

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # Don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        # If bot is mentioned, reply with a message
        if self.user in message.mentions:
            await message.channel.send("You can type `!vx help` for more info.")
            return

def main():
    client = MyClient()
    client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```